# Most pythonic way to split this line?

Tags: python, numpy, pep8, pep

I am trying to reclassify an array that has values from 0 to 15 with new values from 0 to 5.

My conditions are the following:

```
con1 = np.in1d(arr, [0, 11, 13, 15]).reshape((y, x))  # new val 0
con2 = np.in1d(arr, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).reshape((y, x))  # new val 1
con3 = (arr == 6) | (arr == 7)                        # new val 2
con4 = (arr == 8) | (arr == 9)                        # new val 3
con5 = (arr == 10)                                    # new val 4
con6 = (arr == 12) | (arr == 14)                      # new val 5
```

I have the following line in python

```
return np.where(con1, 0, np.where(con2, 1, np.where(con3, 2, np.where(con4, 3, np.where(con5, 4, np.where(con6, 5, arr))))))
```

which is 128 characters long (including the indentation inside the function). PEP8 suggests that lines should not be over 79 characters. However I'm not sure what is the best way to split this line into multiple lines while keeping readability.

I have tried a two options but they seem hard to read.

**Option 1:**

```
return np.where(con1, 0, np.where(
    con2, 1, np.where(
        con3, 2, np.where(
            con4, 3, np.where(
                con5, 4, np.where(
                    con6, 5, arr))))))
```

**Option 2:**

```
return np.where(con1, 0, 
                np.where(con2, 1, 
                         np.where(con3, 2, 
                                  np.where(con4, 3, 
                                           np.where(con5, 4, 
                                                    np.where(con6, 5, arr)
                                                    )))))
```

Comment: What are `con1` and so on like?

Comment: This seems like a code review question : )

Comment: Use the loop, Luke

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do them all seperately. This is more readable as you can follow step by step.

```
filtered_result = np.where(con6, 5, arr)
filtered_result = np.where(con5, 4, filtered_result)
filtered_result = np.where(con4, 3, filtered_result)
filtered_result = np.where(con3, 2, filtered_result)
filtered_result = np.where(con2, 1, filtered_result)
filtered_result = np.where(con1, 0, filtered_result)

return filtered_result
```

To stick with pep8, which is what you're asking, then this is the way to go

**Edit**

A for loop would also significantly reduce the repetitiveness and still be readable.

```
connections = iter((con6, con5, con4, con3, co2, con1, con0))
filters = range(len(connections)-2, 0 -1)

filtered_result = np.where(next(connections), next(filters), arr)

for n, con, in zip(filters, connections):
    filtered_result = np.where(con, n, filtered_result)

return filtered_result
```

Comment: You might even want to use a `for` loop over something like `enumerate([con6, con5, ...])`

Comment: I'll ad that in

Comment: Thought I was going to have problems with overlapping values if I separated the calls but it is not the case. The loop is a good idea, thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Might not be much more readable but you could try `reduce`:

```
from functools import reduce

def some_func():

    ... some code maybe ...

    args = [con1, con2, con3, con4, con5, con6]
    return reduce(
            lambda prev_arg, new_arg: np.where(*new_arg, prev_arg), 
            enumerate(args[:-1]), 
            np.where(args[-1], len(args)-1, arr)
        )
```